# React state mapping acting very strangely?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

So, get this, guys. I retrieve some data from Firebase, and I load it into my `state`, then map it, but I can't seem to do anything useful with it. It gets weirder, because within the `map`, `console.log(mappedValue)` returns the value I expect but `<h1>{mappedValue}</h1>` doesnt. What gives?

The page in question:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { app } from '../helpers/firebaseHelpers.js';


import '../../stylesheets/home.css';
import '../../stylesheets/forms.css';
import '../../App.css';



export class AuthQuotes extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            quotes: []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getQuotes();
        this.props.changePage("quotes");
    }

    getQuotes() {
        this.firebaseRef = app.database().ref(`quotes`);
        var quotes = [];
        this.firebaseRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
            var quote = snapshot.val();
            quote['key'] = snapshot.key;
            quotes.push(quote);
            this.setState({
                quotes: quotes,
            });
        });
    }

    renderQuote(quote) {
        return (
            <h1>hi</h1>
        )
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.quotes[0])
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.quotes.map(quote => {
                    <input type="text" placeholder={quote.person.fName} />
                    console.log(quote.person.fName)
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AuthQuotes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation of why it is working when you removed the `{}`:

There is a valid reason behind everything, there are two **[ways of using arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body)**:

1- Concise body: When we write like this: `a.map(el => el*2)`

2- Block body: When we write like this: `a.map(el => { return el*2; } )`

> With first one, in a concise body, only an expression is specified, which becomes the explicit return value, and in block body, you must use an explicit return statement inside body.

Comment: Both you and @Ali are correct, but you were more thorough than Ali, so I'll accept your answer when I can.

Comment: @Nickdb93 glad, it helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

you forget to return inside `map` method

```
this.state.quotes.map(quote => 
{
    console.log(quote.person.fName);
    return <input type="text" placeholder={quote.person.fName} />
})
```

when you remove the brackets then the return will be implicit

```
this.state.quotes.map(quote => <input type="text" placeholder={quote.person.fName} />)
```

Comment: you're so right. I'm embarrassed that I even posted this question, when I damn well knew this was the reason deep down. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it was a silent syntax error with no actual error message, and I stil really have no idea why it happened. Changing this:

```
{this.state.quotes.map(quote => {
    <input type="text" placeholder={quote.person.fName} />
    console.log(quote.person.fName)
})}
```

To this:

```
{this.state.quotes.map(quote =>
    <input type="text" placeholder={quote.person.fName} />
    console.log(quote.person.fName)
)}
```

(i.e. No curly braces `{` after the delta `=>` made it work. ES6 WTF? If someone can explain to my WHY, WHY DOES THIS HAPPEN TO GOOD PEOPLE, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: checkout my answer